# How can I combine multiple enums when converting from a string?

Tags: c++, class, enums

Inspired by [this question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135293/basic-pokedex-in-c), I'm learning some of the basics of C++ partly by writing a Pokedex. I'm currently at the point where I'm defining the Pokemon types in an enum:

```
enum class basicPokemonType
{
    Normal,
    Fire,
    Water,    
    //etc.
};
```

In the accepted answer on Code Review, the writer then recommends combining these into a combined class, which I do as follows (comments are there for me to make sure I understand what I'm doing):

```
class combinedPokemonType
{
    combinedPokemonType(basicPokemonType primary);
    combinedPokemonType(basicPokemonType primary, basicPokemonType secondary); //overloading constructor in case we have two types

    combinedPokemonType convertStringToPokemonType(std::string primary, std::string secondary = "")

};
```

In the code, I read each of the Pokemon into a stream from a text file like this example:

> 1, Bulbasaur, Grass and Poison, 15.2, 28, Male and Female, 0,

As you can see, Pokemon can have more than one type. My current function to convert the string into my defined enum is as follows:

```
combinedPokemonType combinedPokemonType::convertStringToPokemonType(std::string primary, std::string secondary="")
{
    if (primary == "Normal")
    {
        return combinedPokemonType(basicPokemonType::Normal);
    }
    else if (primary == "Fire")
    {
        return combinedPokemonType(basicPokemonType::Fire);
    }
    else if (primary == "Water")
    {
        return combinedPokemonType(basicPokemonType::Water);
    }
    // etc.
}
```

How can I cover the circumstances where there are more than two types? Do I need to continue my `if` statement and define every possible combination between each of them? I can't help but feel there must be an easier way.

Alternatively, if I am missing something obvious, or trying something that is clearly far beyond my current abilities, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Two methods:  1) Use two separate variables for the types; 2) Make the `enum` values powers of 2 (bit positions) so you can arithmetic OR them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My usual suggestion is to implement this as a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`:

```
std::map<std::string, basicPokemonType> const types_map = {
{"Fire", basicPokemonType::Fire},
{"Normal", basicPokemonType::Normal},
{"Water", basicPokemonType::Water},
/*...*/
};

combinedPokemonType combinedPokemonType::convertStringToPokemonType(std::string primary, std::string secondary="")
{
    auto it = types_map.find(primary);
    if(it != types_map.end())
        return combinedPokemonType(*it);
    else
        //Whatever your error condition is if the string isn't a valid type
}
```

This doesn't prevent you from having to write out each individual pair, but it does make the code cleaner and cut down on the repetitive `if`/`else if`/`else` statements.

Comment: Thanks Xirema. It's a shame there's no way of avoiding typing out every combination, but this definitely helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a pokemon's type as having a [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) of raw types. To check if a pokemon is a particular type, you can ask the pokemon's type set to see if it contains that raw type. This is also flexible in that it would support a pokemon with three or more types if they are ever added.